# Display the job title concatenated with the max salary (separated by a : and space) and name the column "Job Salary Range". Use concat function

Tags: sql

The HR department has requested a report of all jobs descriptions and max salaries. Display the job title concatenated with the max salary (separated by a : and space) and name the column "Job Salary Range". Use concat function

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
SELECT CONCAT(job_title,' ',tot) FROM(
    SELECT
        job_title, max(salary) as tot
    FROM
        table
    GROUP BY
        job_title
) sub_query
```